# Datadog alerts | Slack notifications

Tags: monitoring, slack, metrics, datadog, datadog-dashboard

I have set up event-based alerting on Datadog and notifications on slack.

I am receiving **2 events triggered this monitor, here is the last one.**
I want both events' data to show, not just the last one.
[Alert screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/if8VU.png)

Can someone help me here, please?

---

I did not find anything as of now